# Do I need to study alternative splicing and isoformswitch separately?

Tags: differential-expression, rna-splicing, isoform

I have done a study on isoform switch between different tissue type. Now, many people asking me to study alternative splicing also. But, dont they will give me same results? If there is a significant splicing difference; that will definitely leads to isoform switch. Or my understanding is incorrect ?

Thanks

Comment: Imaging isoform A uses exon 1, and isoform B uses exon 2. Now if you do an isoform switch analysis, you might see that in one condition isoform A (and exon 1) is preferred over isoform B (and exon 2). You might get similar results for alternative splicing. But if there is another isoform C that uses both exon 1 and 2, then the alternative splicing analysis of these exons are going to be affected by the expression level of isoform C as well.

Comment: Thanks @PhoenixMu